# Female lead with pink hair who has a system

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime

The first story she is in, she is the ex of the main protagonist and when they break up, she goes after his father, who is much better. In this part, the father takes her in since he has trouble sleeping and the voice of the girl can help him. Also, the system that helps the protagonist looks like a hamster or something like that.
The female lead has pink hair and the story is similar to "Cheating men must die".

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You tagged this both anime and manga, which is it?  When and where did you see/read this?

Comment: It could be both manga and anime.